# Delete photos from icloud but keep in macbook and phone

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, icloud

I find iCloud really annoying and I want to remove my files (mainly photos) from it but still keep them in my phone and laptop. How should i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

For the laptop, move your photos to a separate folder, desktop for easily finding it, then delete them from iCloud. On your phone, just upload the photos to your laptop and delete them from the phone, then turn off photos in iCloud.